# input for torch.nn.functional.gumbel_softmax

Tags: pytorch, softmax

Say I have a tensor named `attn_weights` of size [1,a], entries of which indicate the attention weights between the given query and |a| keys. I want to select the largest one using `torch.nn.functional.gumbel_softmax`.

I find [docs about this function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html?highlight=gumbel%20softmax#torch.nn.functional.gumbel_softmax) describe the parameter as ***logits*** *- […, num_features] unnormalized log probabilities*. I wonder **whether should I take `log` of `attn_weights` before passing it into `gumbel_softmax`?** And I find Wiki defines `logit=lg(p/1-p)`, which is different from barely logrithm. I wonder which one should I pass to the function?

Further, I wonder **how to choose `tau`** in `gumbel_softmax`, any guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder whether should I take `log` of `attn_weights` before passing it into `gumbel_softmax`?

If `attn_weights` are probabilities (sum to 1; e.g., output of a softmax), then yes. Otherwise, no.

> I wonder how to choose `tau` in `gumbel_softmax`, any guidelines?

Usually, it requires tuning. The references provided in the docs can help you with that.

From [Categorical Reparameterizaion with Gumbel-Softmax](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01144.pdf):

- Figure 1, caption:

  > ... (a) For low temperatures (τ = 0.1, τ = 0.5), the expected value of a Gumbel-Softmax random variable approaches the expected value of a categorical random variable with the same logits. As the temperature increases (τ = 1.0, τ = 10.0), the expected value converges to a uniform distribution over the categories.
- Section 2.2, 2nd paragraph (emphasis mine):

  > While Gumbel-Softmax samples are differentiable, they are not identical to samples from the corresponding categorical distribution for non-zero temperature. For learning, **there is a tradeoff between small temperatures**, where samples are close to one-hot but the variance of the gradients is large, **and large temperatures**, where samples are smooth but the variance of the gradients is small (Figure 1). **In practice, we start at a high temperature and anneal to a small but non-zero temperature**.
- Lastly, they remind the reader that tau can be learned:

  > If τ is a learned parameter (rather than annealed via a fixed
  > schedule), this scheme can be interpreted as entropy regularization (Szegedy et al., 2015; Pereyra et al., 2016), where the Gumbel-Softmax distribution can adaptively adjust the "confidence" of proposed samples during the training process.

Comment: I'll check out the paper carefully soon