# unnormalized vs log probability in gumbel softmax

Tags: pytorch, softmax

I am trying to figure out the input of the torch.gumbel_softmax, or just gumbel softmax in general. From its original [paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rkE3y85ee) it seems like the authors are using the normalized categorical log probability:

> The Gumbel-Max trick (Gumbel, 1954; Maddison et al., 2014) provides a simple and efficient way
> to draw samples z from a categorical distribution with class probabilities π: z = one_hot(argmax_i[g_i + log π_i])

However, from some other posts ([2](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Eewein//blog/2022/03/04/gumbel-max/),[3](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/07/31/gumbel-max-trick/)) as well as from torch.nn.functional.gumbel_softmax [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.gumbel_softmax.html) they are saying the input should be the unnormalized category probability.

Empirically I think using unnormalized prob makes more sense because it seems more reasonable to add gumbel noise to unconstrained numbers instead of normalized probabilities, but I would like to get a more concrete answer.

I am aware there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980330/input-for-torch-nn-functional-gumbel-softmax), but it doesn't thoroughly solve my question.